# FileNotFoundException (Not a directory)

Tags: java, exception, java-io, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I've been trying to read a text file for more than a day now, but no matter what I do, it always goes wrong.

I'll simplify my code:

I have a File object:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty(user.dir) + "/src/com/ksa/voetje/savedFiles/savedSettings.txt");
```

If I print the directory out, I get "/Users/jonaseveraert/IdeaProjects/Voetje KSA/src/com/ksa/voetje/savedFiles/savedSettings.txt".

I also have a Scanner, and this is where I keep getting errors:

```
Scanner reader = null;
try {
   reader = new Scanner(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I keep getting the FileNotFoundException, even though the file is there!
Here is the error message (reader = new Scanner(file) is at line 42):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/jonaseveraert/IdeaProjects/Voetje KSA/src/com/ksa/voetje/savedFiles/savedSettings.txt/Users/jonaseveraert/IdeaProjects/Voetje KSA/src/com/ksa/voetje/savedFiles/savedSettings.txt (Not a directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:639)
    at com.ksa.voetje.savedFiles.FileReader.readLines(FileReader.java:42)
    at com.ksa.voetje.instellingen.previousSettings.SettingsReader.getPreviousSettings(SettingsReader.java:22)
    at com.ksa.voetje.instellingen.previousSettings.SettingsReader.<init>(SettingsReader.java:14)
    at com.ksa.voetje.instellingen.previousSettings.PreviousSettings.<init>(PreviousSettings.java:11)
    at com.ksa.voetje.display.DisplaySystem.<init>(DisplaySystem.java:94)
    at com.ksa.voetje.Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
```

The error tells me the path I gave to file is not a directory, I don't understand why it gives me this error.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: in error message the url is `/Users/jonaseveraert/IdeaProjects/Voetje KSA/src/com/ksa/voetje/savedFiles/savedSettings.txt/Users/jonaseveraert/IdeaProjects/Voetje KSA/src/com/ksa/voetje/savedFiles/savedSettings.txt` Why  the path is repeated twice? Are you doing something with the path object before using scanner?

Comment: @onkarruikar I did not notice that, I'll have to find what's wrong with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileNotFoundException` is also thrown when the file cannot be accessed. Make sure your file has the correct permissions to allow Java to access it.

Another thing I saw in the code is that the path starts at
`"/Users/"`. Shouldn't it be `"C:/Users/"`?

Comment: It is not a permissions problem.  The problem is that the path is mangled.  The path is telling the OS that `savedSettings.txt` "should be" a directory ... but it isn't.

Comment: The problem was indeed that path is mangled, I fixed it and then also noticed i didn't have permission. Also,  think C: only applies to Windows? So I'll have to check if my program works on Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

> The error tells me the path I gave to file is not a directory, I don't understand why it gives me this error.

Because you *asked* it to interpret `savedSettings.txt` as a directory.

Oh yes you did!!

According to the exception message, this is the pathname for the file you were using:

```
 /Users/jonaseveraert/IdeaProjects/Voetje KSA/src/com/ksa/
 voetje/savedFiles/savedSettings.txt/Users/jonaseveraert/
 IdeaProjects/Voetje KSA/src/com/ksa/voetje/savedFiles/savedSettings.txt
```

(I have added some line breaks added for readability.)

Notice on the 2nd line `savedSettings.txt` is followed by `/Users`.  For that to make sense, the `savedSettings.txt` needs to resolve to a directory.  Apparently, it doesn't.  Hence the error message saying "its not a directory"<sup>1</sup>.

The problem is in the way you are assembling the pathname ... or what you are assembling it from.

You say:

> If I print the directory out, I get "/Users/jonaseveraert/IdeaProjects/Voetje KSA/src/com/ksa/voetje/savedFiles/savedSettings.txt".

It is not clear what you are actually printing, but it is NOT the pathname denoted by the `File` that you are passing to the `Scanner` constructor. The exception message does not lie.

---

<sup>1 - Granted, the exception message is a bit misleading.  It would be more helpful if it said that something in that path doesn't resolve to a directory.  But unfortunately, the error information returned by the OS is non-specific, and it would be complicated (and expensive) for Java to try to work out which name isn't a directory.</sup>